# What part of this simple Javascript calculator is wrong?

Tags: javascript

I've recently wrote this simple javascript calculator but it will not work, got any ideas?

```js
function calculateMe() {
   var x = document.getElementById("x"); 
   var y = document.getElementById("y"); 
   var e = x + y;
   document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = e;
    
}
```

```html
<center><input id="x"></input> +
<input id="y"></input><br><br>
    <button onclick="calculateMe()">Submit</button><br><br>
        <input id="a"></input>
```

Comment: you have to use parseInt

Comment: Could you please be more specific than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first get the value from the inputs, then set the value like:

```js
function calculateMe() {
    var x = +document.getElementById("x").value;
    var y = +document.getElementById("y").value;
    var e = x + y;
    document.getElementById("a").value = e;
}
```

```html
    <input id="x"></input>+
    <input id="y"></input>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="calculateMe()">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="a"></input>
```

The `+` in the document.getElementById code turns the strings you get into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function calculateMe() {
            var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("x").value); 
            if(isNaN(x)){
                x = 0;
                document.getElementById("x").value=x;
                alert("The value in the first text box is not a valid number.");
            }
            var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("y").value);
            if(isNaN(y)){
                y = 0;
                document.getElementById("y").value=y;
                alert("The value in the second text box is not a valid number.");
            }           
            var e = x + y;
            document.getElementById("a").value = e;
        }
        </script>
        <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <input id="x" type="text"> +
            <input id="y" type="text"><br><br>
            <button onclick="calculateMe()">Submit</button><br><br>
            <input id="a" type="text" readonly>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```